# Monitor total service uptime using Icinga

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring, icinga

I am using Icinga (Nagios fork) for monitoring ~10 webservers, each one providing different services. 
I would now like to provide an aggregated view on the server states on our companies intranet, providing information like:

```
server | state | last downtime | Ø uptime (month) | Ø uptime (year)
Srv1   | OK    | 2013-10-09    | 99,5%            | 99,8 %
Srv2   | ERROR | 2013-10-31    | 73,1%            | 85,4 %
```

Is there a possibility to get those values from icinga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the IDOUtils database backend including all relevant historical data (statehistory, downtimes, notifications) and then use the icinga reporting package within jasper reports. If the provided sample reports do not fit your needs, you can create your own reports with ireport and export them to pdf (and other formats) as well as schedule sla reports being sent on an interval basis.

Depending on your installation method, you may either recompile the source and enable IDOUtils, or install it as additional package (including mysql). Then install jasper and icinga reporting - http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/reporting.html

The reporting itsself can also integrated in Icinga web as cronk widget if required.

Comment: Thank you. I am now using IDOUtils and the default cgi-scripts (status.cgi and avail.cgi), which can provide json-output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pnp4nagios you can get perfdata from the servers, you also need to add the checks for nrpe to run check_uptime to graph the perf data or using snmp.
Once you've got that data other than just a "ping" to check on the servers you can create a filter in the web-icinga to show the status/duration for each one as well as use the pnp4nag data. I believe you can also find a conk to display the uptime status in that manner but I havent gone that far to check.
some references...
[Where are Nagios Availability-Report files stored?](https://serverfault.com/questions/461694/where-are-nagios-availability-report-files-stored)
for manual pointer for the cgi
OR
this addon
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Reporting/Nagios-Availability-Reports-to-pdf/details